# Vungle Unity Plugin Video Ad closed automatically

Tags: unity-game-engine, vungle-ads

I have a strange problem with Vungle Unity Plugin, After video completes, **AD popup automatically closes in iOS devices**. It's not waiting for the user to click the close button. Generally when a video completes, a close button appears and wait for the user to press it. **But, here occasionally, for some videos, it's automatically getting closed after video completes.**

```
**Vungle :**
#### VERSION 3.1.10
* Integrated iOS Publisher SDK v3.2.1


**Unity:**
Version 5.4.0 p2
Pro Version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name is Aki from Vungle.
We have some types of ads which don't have endcard. Those ads will close automatically after finishing video part.

Please let me know if you have further questions.

Thanks,
-aki